# regex - match empty space between any of characters

Tags: php, regex

In PHP it is a common practice to treat strings as immutable. Sometimes there's a need to modify a string "in-place".

We go with the additional array creation approach.

This array should contain every single letter from the source string.

There's a function for that in PHP (str_split). One issue, it doesn't handle multibyte encodings well enough.

There's also a mb_split function which takes a regex as an input parameter for separator sequence. So

```
mb_split('.', '123')
```

returns ['', '', '', ''].

BUT:

```
mb_split('', '123')
```

returns ['123'].

So I believe there is a counterpart regex which matches empty space between any variation of multi-byte character sequence.

So for '123' it should match

```
'1~2', '2~3'
```

where ~ is an actual match. That is just like \b but for anything.

Is there a regex hack to do so?

Comment: What do you have an what do you need? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I'm doing a work where I should present the most simple code for a group of students preparing to pass a coding interview. The question is in-place string reversal. There is a need for a solution presentation with the use of PHP language. To promote best coding practices we decided to use the commonly used approach to count PHP strings as immutable. So we have no right to use string character accessors as a language feature. We create an array from that string instead and work on that, reversing it by swapping the elements then combining to a resulting string. We can't use complex solutions.

Comment: If it is working for at-least UTF-8 that is already a nearly perfect solution.

Comment: [^\u0000-\uFFFF] - no luck

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~\X~u', $s, $arr)` - the `$arr[0]` must contain all the characters. See http://ideone.com/RCvvl4.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: this cracks the nut. Please add as an answer so that I could mark it accepted.

Comment: Just found another, similar solution based on the same `\X` pattern with `preg_split`: [`$res = preg_split('~(?=\X)~u', "Wełkam", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`](https://ideone.com/8DX2Kw).

Comment: Thanks! Hope that will blow minds ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
preg_match_all('~\X~u', $s, $arr)
```

The `$arr[0]` will contain all the characters. The `\X` pattern [matches any Unicode grapheme](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme). The `/u` modifier is necessary to make the regex engine treat the input string as a Unicode string and make the pattern Unicode aware.

See the [PHP dem](http://ideone.com/RCvvl4)o.